# RxJs - (why) Does an Observable emit it's latest value on a new subsription?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Ok, this is a quick one, i'm kinda exhausted already and am confusing myself :D

I'm working with angular2 and RxJS Observables.

I have a service with a property "data", which is an Observable that get's set in the constructor, and a method to return this observable to subscribe to.

```
export class test{
    private data: Observable<Object>
    constructor(private http: Http){
       this.data = this.http.get(url).map( res => res.json());
    }  
    getData(): Observable<Object>{
       return this.data
    }
}
```

I have worked wit replaySubjects a while ago to always emit all values of the sequence to new subscribers. However, with the code above the Observable seems to emit it's latest value to new subscribers. Is this intended?

```
test(i: number) {
      if (i > 0) {
        setTimeout( () => {
          this.dataService.getData().subscribe( (data) => {
            this.debug.log(data);
            this.test(i-1);
          });
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
test(4)
```

I get a value for every iteration. I am confused, 'cause a year ago when i wanted that behaviour, i got no new values when subscribing 'too late'.
Essentially, i just want to cache the result of the http.get, and deliver the same value to all subscribers, instead of making a new http request for every subscription (returning the http.get(url).. in getData())

Comment: Does `this.http.get(url).map( res => res.json()).share()` do what you want?

Comment: I'm confused. You say the observer is emitting its last value for new subscribers, which you don't seem to like. Then you say that's what you wanted. What is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, on the phone and tired and ..... Yes, it behaves the way i want. I'm just not sure if it is intended, since a year ago it didn't work like that (or at least i think that). I guess i should jsut read up on observables again when i have the time later

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but the answers seem to me quite confusing.

The Observable you return from the method getData() is just that, an Observable. So every time a consumer subscribes it gets the response. So it is working fine, but it is indeed making a new request every time.

In order to cache the result there are plenty of ways to do it depending on the behavior you want. To just cache a single request I would recommend t use the #publishBehavior operator:

```
export class test{
  private data: Observable<Object>;
  constructor(private http: Http){
    this.data = this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .publishBehavior([])
      .refCount();
  }  
  getData(): Observable<Object>{
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

The parameter passed to the publishBehavior is the initial value. With this two operators, the request will be made when the first subscriber arrived. Next subscribers will get the cached answer.

In others answers the use of Subjects has been suggested. The publishBehavior is using subjects under the hood. But to directly call next() it is consider bad practice unless there is no other remedy, and thats not the case for this scenario in my opinion. Even if you use Subjects directly, it will be wise to return an Observable to the Components by using the #asObservable() operator so the component won't have access to the next, error and complete methods.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to use `Subject` for this. It has a method `next()` to which you will send your newly arrived property so that it pushes it to the subscribers.

In addition to this, you should create a service that will be a singleton. Whenever your components instantiate it in a constructor, they will receive the object already formed with all the data. There will be no need to fetch the data every time.

Also, instead of instantiating your data in the constructor, implement `OnInit` and do the calls to the server from there.

Comment: It is a service (this.dataService.getData()), and since i use ng2 DI it is a singleton for the scope of my app. Since the service has no view/data-bound inputs, i think using the constructor is ok ?